# Image link and title link rearranagement

Tags: php, joomla

Following are the codes where Image link is coming first and then the title link comes. And I want to make it opposite way. Title link which is calling in (span) should be coming first and then the image link. It would be a great help if anyone can solve this out.

```
if ($item->menu_image) {
$item->params->get('menu_text', 1 ) ?
$linktype = '<img src="'.$item->menu_image.'" alt="'.$item->title.'" /><span class="image-title">'.$item->title.'</span>' :
$linktype = '<img src="'.$item->menu_image.'" alt="'.$item->title.'" />';
} else {
$linktype = $item->title;
}
```

I need to rearrange the menu image url link where image-title will come first and then menu_image will come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I did not understand exactly your request, is this what you need?

```
if ($item->menu_image) {
$item->params->get('menu_text', 1 ) ?
$linktype = '<span class="image-title">'.$item->title.'</span><img src="'.$item->menu_image.'" alt="'.$item->title.'" />' :
$linktype = '<img src="'.$item->menu_image.'" alt="'.$item->title.'" />';
} else {
$linktype = $item->title;
}
```